# Escaping double quotes in string

Tags: shell, text-processing, quoting

I have a string message which contains data in double quotes. I need to put `\` in front of every double quote how can u do it in shell ?

I used Perl and it works fine, but I'm looking for `sh` command:

```
cat sampleMetadata | perl -wpe 's/([\\"])/\\$1/g'
```

Comment: Your Perl one can be shorter `perl -wpe 's/"/\\$&/g'`

Answer (score 2):

With standard tools chest, `sed` is a good one:

```
sed -e 's/"/\\&/g' <sampleMetadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to escape double-quotes (and other special simbols) put all line(s) in single qoutes (if it is absent in your text):

```
sed "s/^\|$/'/g" <sampleMetadata
```